# Максимальная зарплата у людей, которым по 25 лет

Tags: mysql, sql

> При выборке из таблицы workers создайте новое поле max,  в котором
>   будет лежать максимальное значение зарплаты для возраста 25 лет.

Я сделал, работает, можно ли как-нибудь сократить?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   workers 
WHERE  salary = (SELECT Max(salary) AS max 
                 FROM   workers 
                 WHERE  age = 25) 
       AND age = 25
```

Comment: так выведет только максимальную зарплату, а надо вывести все поля у пользователя

Comment: `так выведет только максимальную зарплату` - разве? там же звезда у вас написана..........  кстати последние `AND age = 25` вроде как не нужны, раз во внутреннем запросе уже применяется это условие

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нужны, иначе туда попадут люди с такой же зп, но с другим возрастом. Была похожая задача на sql-ex в свое время)

Comment: То, что возвращает ваш запрос отличается от того, что написано в задании. Ваш запрос ведет 25 летних работников и максимальную зарплату для 25 лет. А по заданию надо вывести всех работников и максимальную зарплату для 25 лет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну какже, а если 45-летний получает тоже максимальную зарплату

Comment: Сам вопрос не совсем ясен. Что значит "создать новое поле при выборке"? В общей выборке данных из таблицы `workers` выводить дополнительное поле с максимальной зарплатой для возраста 25 лет?

Answer (score 2):

у вас в условии ничего не сказано о том, что вы должны ограничивать выборку по условиям, а только добавить дополнительное поле, правильный запрос по вашему описанию задачи будет таким:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT Max(salary)  
     FROM   workers 
     WHERE  age = 25
    ) AS  'max'
FROM   workers
```

Comment: Это ваш вопрос, перечитайте на досуге ;)

Comment: @DivMan это действительно ответ на ваш вопрос. Как задан вопрос, такой и ответ :)